# VS Code: How do you add breakpoints accross several windows? (python)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I open a file in a separate window via ctrl shift P -> open active file in a new window, any breakpoints I set in the new window aren't hit when I debug from my original VS Code instance. Is there some setting to make sure that the newly spawned window belongs to the original VS Code instance? Or is there some alternative way that I should be using when using VS Code on a multi monitor setup?

Answer (score 0):

For complex scenarios involving more than one process (for example, a client and a server), VS Code supports multi-target debugging.

Using multi-target debugging is simple: after you've started a first debug session, you can just launch another session. As soon as a second session is up and running, the VS Code UI switches to multi-target mode